# clamav update issue using proxy authentication

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, ubuntu-16.04, antivirus, clam

I am having trouble using proxy authentication for updating clamav. I added proxy information in /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf as shown below :-

```
# Proxy Setup
HTTPProxyServer myproxy
HTTPProxyPort 3128
HTTPProxyUsername proxyuser
HTTPProxyPassword proxypass
```

On saving the file, I get the following warning.

```
WARNING: Insecure permissions (for HTTPProxyPassword): /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf must have no more than 0700 permissions.
```

So I change the file permissions to 700 as suggested. Now I am getting an error.

```
ERROR: Can't open/parse the config file /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf
```

If I roll-back the permissions, it gives me warning. If I apply permissions I get an error, either case I can't get clamav to update.

It is only when I remove the authentication it tries to connect(I have to roll back permissions to 444 default), and I get the following error:-

```
Thu May 12 09:28:35 2017 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu May 12 09:28:35 2017
Thu May 12 09:28:35 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:28:35 2017 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Thu May 12 09:28:35 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:28:35 2017 -> WARNING: getfile: Unknown response from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:28:35 2017 -> WARNING: Can't download daily.cvd from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:28:36 2017 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
Thu May 12 09:28:41 2017 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu May 12 09:28:41 2017
Thu May 12 09:28:41 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:28:41 2017 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Thu May 12 09:28:41 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:28:41 2017 -> WARNING: getfile: Unknown response from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:28:41 2017 -> WARNING: Can't download daily.cvd from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:28:42 2017 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
Thu May 12 09:28:47 2017 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu May 12 09:28:47 2017
Thu May 12 09:28:47 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:28:47 2017 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Thu May 12 09:28:47 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:28:48 2017 -> WARNING: getfile: Unknown response from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:28:48 2017 -> WARNING: Can't download daily.cvd from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:28:48 2017 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
Thu May 12 09:28:53 2017 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu May 12 09:28:53 2017
Thu May 12 09:28:53 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:28:53 2017 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Thu May 12 09:28:53 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:28:54 2017 -> WARNING: getfile: Unknown response from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:28:54 2017 -> WARNING: Can't download daily.cvd from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:28:54 2017 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
Thu May 12 09:28:59 2017 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu May 12 09:28:59 2017
Thu May 12 09:28:59 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:28:59 2017 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Thu May 12 09:28:59 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:29:00 2017 -> ERROR: getfile: Unknown response from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:29:00 2017 -> ERROR: Can't download daily.cvd from db.local.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:29:00 2017 -> Giving up on db.local.clamav.net...
Thu May 12 09:29:00 2017 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu May 12 09:29:00 2017
Thu May 12 09:29:00 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:29:00 2017 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Thu May 12 09:29:00 2017 -> Connecting via myproxy
Thu May 12 09:29:01 2017 -> ERROR: getfile: Unknown response from database.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:29:01 2017 -> ERROR: Can't download daily.cvd from database.clamav.net
Thu May 12 09:29:01 2017 -> Giving up on database.clamav.net...
Thu May 12 09:29:01 2017 -> Update failed. Your network may be down or none of the mirrors listed in /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf is working. Check http://www.clamav.net/doc/mirrors-faq.html for possible reasons.
```

I have tried all I can find. I did reconfigure as well

```
> dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
```

still the same result. The way I see this clamav is uanble to connect using proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure the configuration file owned by the same user as is running clamav.
2. Look at your proxy logs to see what is failing while downloading the daily file?

Comment: Awesome,that did the trick, The file was owned by a different user, changing ownership fixed the issue.